# Input [type=file] returns empty value

Tags: python, upload, web.py

I have a script that creates a popup with form according to webpy cookbook:

```
jQuery('#logo').click(function(){
    var content = ('<h1>Upload logo</h1>' +
        '<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/upload">' +
        '<input type="file" id="myfile" accept="image/jpeg,image/png,image/gif" />' +
        '<button id="upload" type="submit">Загрузить</button></form>'
        );
    popup(content);
});
```

in my python app I have a simple code for relevant class:

```
class uploadPage(allpages):
    def POST(self):
        x = web.input(myfile={})
        print x
```

but when I try to upload file I always get empty Storage object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<input type="file" />` element has no name attribute which would indicate the name of the file in the form submission. The name is required since you can have multiple input fields, including `file` ones, in one form. Adding `name=` should fix your problem:

```
'<input type="file" name="myfile" id="myfile" accept="image/jpeg,image/png,image/gif" />'
//                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```